# How to call a javascript function when we select a value from apex input list attribute

Tags: visualforce, community

```
<apex:inputText list="{!listOfStringElements}" id="userInput" onChange="alert(this.value);"></apex:inputText>
```

In the above code when I select any value from the listOfStringElements I want to call a javascript function. Onchange on the above code works when after selecting the value I click anywhere on the screen but I want to call it as soon as i select any value from the list.

Comment: See e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/574941/best-way-to-track-onchange-as-you-type-in-input-type-text if it's a text field as it appears to be from the markup.

Comment: it should work on change event. I can't see your code for Onchange.

Comment: @Ricky onchange works when I select the value from the list and then click anywhere else on the page but I want the value in javascript function as soon as I select the value from the list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Try Using '**html-oninput**' instead on 'onChange'

Your code edited:

```
<apex:inputText list="{!listOfStringElements}" id="userInput" html-oninput="alert(this.value);"></apex:inputText>
```

I hope this helps :)

Comment: OnKeypress works when I enter the value using the keyboard but I want the alert when I click on any of the value from the dropdown list.

Comment: Oh, Got it. I changed the above code as per your requirement. It should work now. Please check it once.